# How to add SipAddHeader for all calls?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

There is telephony based on FreePBX Distro.
The task, for all calls (internal, outgoing, incoming) in the SIP Header to add the UNIQUEID value, for further analysis of calls in CRM.
In extensions_custom.conf I add:

```
exten => _., 1, SIPaddheader (Unique-ID: $ {UNIQUEID})
```

And when receiving an incoming call from another extension, we see that the necessary information has been received:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgx0N.png)
No matter how SIPaddheader did in this file, it is not possible to add UNIQUEID to the header of outgoing calls, and incoming from outside.

Answer (score 1):

SIPAddHeader do adding headers only for next ONE outbound and only to first invite.

For incoming calls use channels variables.

Please note, that some applications like ringgroup and queues may create much more then one channel, so you need use inheritance(add two underscore before variable name). Check asterisk doc for more info.

There are no sinlge place for make it perfect, you should understand freepbx internals.